# Java type inference fails: <captured wildcard> is not a functional interface

Tags: javac, jls

With the java 8 compiler, this program:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
public class xx {
    public void execute(Consumer<? super Runnable> executor, Runnable action) {
        executor.accept(() -> action.run());
    }
}
```

fails with:

```
xx.java:4: error: incompatible types: <captured wildcard> is not a functional interface
        executor.accept(() -> action.run());
                        ^
```

Obviously the compiler failed to infer the type of `() -> action.run()`.

This is easy to fix either by changing `? super Runnable` to `Runnable`, or by explicitly casting the lambda to `Runnable`.

My question: this failure seems kindof "dumb".. is this behavior specified by the JLS, or is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 0):

Capture of `? super Runnable` represents a given but unknown super type of `Runnable` (could possibly be `Object`). To classify a type as a functional interface you need an upper bound, not a lower bound. Inferring the type of a lambda, OTOH, requires a function interface as its target type.